# Angular routerLinkActive only updates after clicking somewhere on the screen

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-routerlink

Using Angular 13

I have a side menu which I build like this

```
<mat-nav-list>
  <a mat-list-item *ngFor="let page of pages" [routerLink]="page.link" routerLinkActive="is-active">
    <mat-icon style="padding-right:5px;">{{page?.icon}}</mat-icon>
    <span [@animateText]="linkText ? 'show' : 'hide'">{{ page?.name }} </span>
  </a>
</mat-nav-list>
```

Then I have a list of pages:

```
public pages: Page[] = [
    {name: 'Home', link: '/home', icon: 'home'},
    {name: 'Data', link: '/data', icon: 'format_list_bulleted'},
    {name: 'Reports', link: '/reports', icon: 'bar_chart'},
  ];
```

When I click on a menu item, my page gets loaded correctly but routerLinkActive does not assign the class until I click anywhere on the screen. After that the class is there and I get the css on my menu to highlight the item. I am stuck on this and haven´t found anyone asking this. Could this be a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: No error in the console? Your code looks good.

Comment: There´s no error shown. It works, it just waits for a click to update and I get no other feedback

Answer (score 1):

Try !important in your css:

```
.is-active{
    //your css with !important;
}
```

Reason: mat-list-item css is overshadowing the css defined inside is-active rule.

Answer (score 0):

Since your ***View*** is changing when you route the menu items, I suggest you to use Change Detector Ref to get the changes manually on your Component either;
in the constructor or ngOnInit method.

```
constructor(changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef){
this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();}

// OR 

ngOnInit(){
this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
}
```

[A question that mentions where should Change Detector to be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66819852/when-to-use-changedetectorref-angular)

[Check this Angular document also](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef)

Comment: Thanks, this is something useful I´ll keep in mind but does not solve this issue

Comment: I would like to look into the .ts file that you're trying to route from @ReneTrujillo